# In M.U.G.E.N, how do I resize the stages?

Tags: pc, mugen

Well, I recently asked a question on how to resize the background in the selection menu, but now I have this question to ask.

Out of my 50 stages, about 15 or so are too zoomed in. This causes the fighters to appear floating in the air when fighting. For example, a stage takes place in a dungeon. A person  in the background was supposed to be standing in level with the fighters, but instead, the person is a lot lower than the fighters. The fighters were also above the "ground", proving that the stage was zoomed in

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: The reason this happened is because the stage I used is a high-res stage. Those don't work on low-res mugens. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the "ground" position of the stage.

In the stages folder (mugen\stages), look for the corresponding def file. It's like Stage0.def, Stage1.def, ...

Edit this file with some text editor (notepad).
Change the atribute `zoffset` in `[StageInfo]` of the desired stage.

Example:

```
[StageInfo]
zoffset = 190
```

The value 190 is the number of pixels from the top of the screen.